# Pinescript V5 - RSI from oversold to crossing 50 entry signal

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, rsi

Hello I need some help with an indicator I have built please. Pinescript v5.

I have an rsi with an overbought , oversold and mid line. I’m trying to code an entry signal that only shows if the rsi line moved into the oversold region first and then crosses the mid line.

So the entry signal shows only when the rsi crosses the mid line, but it has to have crossed the oversold region prior to that.

Thanks to anyone who can help Iv tried finding an answer for days

Answer (score 0):

```
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
rsilb = 25
rsimb = 50
rsiub = 75

buy = ta.lowest(rsi, 10) <= rsilb and ta.crossover(rsi, rsimb)
// rsi was below lower band in the last 10 candles and is crossing over middle band
sell = ta.highest(rsi, 10) >= rsiub and ta.crossunder(rsi, rsimb)
//rsi was above upperband in the last 10 candles and is crossing below middle band
```